# Can I use an ng-repeat inside ng-repeat and mingle interpolates?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-interpolate

I've found a couple of other questions of people trying to put ng-repeat inside ng-repeat and that seems doable. But to accomplish what I need to do, I think I also need to put an interpolate from the first ng-repeat into the second ng-repeat. For example:

Before:

```
<div class="mainDetails">
    <li ng-repeat="x in mainLinks" class="{{x.id}}"><a href="{{x.link}}"><img src = "{{x.icon}}" width = "15px" height = "15px">{{x.name}}</a></li>
</div>
<div class="secondDetails">
    <li ng-repeat="x in secondLinks"><a href="{{x.link}}"><img src = "{{x.icon}}" width = "15px" height = "15px">{{x.name}}</a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="thirdDetails">
    <li ng-repeat="x in thirdLinks" class="{{x.id}}"><a href="{{x.link}}"><img src = "{{x.icon}}" width = "15px" height = "15px">{{x.name}}</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

That can get a little crazy especially because I have it actually go up to "eighteenth".

So this is what I thought of:
After:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" class="{{x.count}}Details">
    <li ng-repeat="y in {{x.count}}Links" class="{{y.id}}"><a href="{{y.link}}"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>
</div>
```

numOfMaps coming from:

```
$scope.numOfMaps=[{
        count:"main"
    },{
        count:"second"
    },{
        count:"third"
    }];
```

Then, as I have a need for more "Details" all I need to do is add a count and boom: it is also added to the HTML. I thought it was pretty clever anyway..

The area is just blank, doesn't show anything.

Error in JavaScript Console:
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$parse/syntax?p0=x.count&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bx.count%7D%7DLinks&p4=x.count%7D%7DLinks
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:6:450
    at gb.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:170:252)
    at gb.consume (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:171:181)
    at gb.object (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:179:45)
    at gb.primary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:169:385)
    at gb.unary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:176:73)
    at gb.multiplicative (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:175:310)
    at gb.additive (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:175:170)
    at gb.relational (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:175:34)
    at gb.equality (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:174:400)
    at gb.logicalAND (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:174:281)
    at gb.logicalOR (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:174:151)
    at gb.ternary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:173:461)
    at gb.assignment (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:173:211)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I followed your question correctly, but this is what you can try:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['main', 'first', 'second']" class="{{name}}Details">
    <li ng-repeat="y in this[name + 'Links']" class="{{y.id}}">
        <a href="{{y.link}}">
            <img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">
            {{y.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Keyword `this` in template expressions resolves to the current scope. However this feature is AFAIK undocumented. So it might be better to put those arrays as controller properties and use [`controller as` syntax](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm).

Comment: I was able to keep x in numOfMaps, but what you changed it to does the same thing I am sure. Since that can get pretty long in the HTML I'll just keep it in an object. But the y in this[name + 'Links'] did the trick!